# How i can find out that URL is active or inactive

Tags: iphone

I have One issue i am showing information of web site using web view. Before showing it i want to know is it url link active or not if it is then i will show it in webView otherwise i will show alert message to User. Can anyone help to me. The url is like www.domainname.com:8150/imagename.jpg will it work or not. In this i want to know Will this link active or not.
      Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether your internet connection is alive with well known host. For example you can use the following request:

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
[req release];

2. Then do the same for your url.